# AWK array syntax error (unexpected newline or end of string)

Tags: bash, syntax, awk, syntax-error

i have been trying to run the following bash script, but get error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: -
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I have been trying to figure out what the problem is but to no avail. I need to run the script urgently for a project, so any help will be highly appreciated!

input file (called 'input'):

```
0    13    1495.015    1495.02d0    3.03607E-09    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    14    1598.750    1598.57d0    1.90704E-09    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    15    1701.372    1700.87d0    1.26357E-09    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    16    1803.382    1802.22d0    9.11215E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    17    1906.131    1904.54d0    7.17855E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    18    2009.553    2007.55d0    5.88960E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    19    2113.543    2110.84d0    4.86193E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    20    2217.641    2214.16d0    4.09698E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    21    2321.638    2317.24d0    3.53609E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    22    2426.151    2420.84d0    3.12269E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    23    2530.983    2524.70d0    2.80847E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
0    24    2636.078    2629.18d0    2.52442E-10    0.000000    0.00000E+00
```

script starts:

```
largesep_obs=103.188

avg_n="`awk '{sum_n+=$2} END{avg=sum_n/NR; print(avg)}' input`"

avg_ref="`awk '{sum_ref+=$3} END{avg=sum_ref/NR; print(avg)}' input`"

avg_obs="`awk '{sum_obs+=$4} END{avg=sum_obs/NR; print(avg)}' input`"

num="`awk -v avg_n=$avg_n -v avg_obs=$avg_obs '{sum+=($4-avg_obs)*($2-avg_n); print(sum)}' input`"

den="`awk -v avg_n=$avg_n '{sum+=($2-avg_n)**2}' input`"

largesep_ref=$num/$den

r=1

nu_not=2000

b="( $r*$largesep_ref/$largesep_obs-1 )*( $r*$avg_ref/$avg_obs-1 )**-1"

den_of_a=`awk -v avg_obs=$avg_obs -v avg_ref=$avg_ref -v nu_not=$nu_not -v b="$b" '{sum+=(($4/nu_not)**b)} END{ans=sum/NR; print(ans)}' input`

a=($avg_obs - $r*$avg_ref)/$den_of_a

no_of_rows=12

awk -v nu_not=$nu_not -v r=$r -v a=$a -v b=$b -v no_of_rows=$no_of_rows '\"{
            for (x=1; x<=no_of_rows; x++) {
            array[x]=r*$3 + a*(($4/nu_not)**b)
        print("%s", vector[x])
        print("\n")
            }           
}'\" input
```

Comment: Could you narrow down the problem? You run awk 7 times in the script, which ones are getting the errors?

Comment: I suspect the problem is the `\"` in the last `awk` command. But I can't figure out what you're doing in that one. Why is it running a `for` loop on every line of the input, but not using anything from the input?

Comment: Throw this script away, then post some small sample input and expected output and describe what you want to do and ask for help writing a script to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many things wrong with your script, it's hard to know where to begin.

The first 3 `awk` commands can be done in one script:

```
avgs=(awk '{ sum_n += $2; sum_ref += $3; sum_obs +=$4; }
           END { print sum_n/NR; sum_ref/NR; sum_obs/NR }' input)
avg_n=${avgs[0]}
avg_ref=${avgs[1]}
avg_obs=${avgs[2]}
```

I'm not sure what you're doing in the assignments to `num` and `den`. You're feeding the input file to `awk`, but you're just adding the same thing on each row, not doing anything with the input. In the `num` assignment you're printing the running total for each line, but you later use `$num` as if it just contains a single number; should that `print(sum)` be in an `END` clause? On the other hand, the `awk` command in the `den` assignment doesn't have any `print` command at all, so nothing gets assigned there.

```
b="( $r*$largesep_ref/$largesep_obs-1 )*( $r*$avg_ref/$avg_obs-1 )**-1"
a=($avg_obs - $r*$avg_ref)/$den_of_a
```

don't perform the calculations, they just assign the whole formula as a string to the variables. If you want to calculate, you need to use `let` or `((...))`:

let b=( $r*$largesep_ref/$largesep_obs-1 )*( $r*$avg_ref/$avg_obs-1 )**-1
   a=(( ($avg_obs - $r*$avg_ref)/$den_of_a) )

The last `awk` command should be:

```
awk -v nu_not=$nu_not -v r=$r -v a="$a" -v b="$b" -v no_of_rows=$no_of_rows '{
            for (x=1; x<=no_of_rows; x++) {
            array[x]=r*$3 + a*(($4/nu_not)**b)
        print("%s", vector[x])
        print("\n")
            }           
}' input
```

The error message about `-` was coming from not quoting `$a` -- it was seeing the `-` in `$a` as a separate argument, and interpreted that as the input file to read from (meaning stdin). But the expansion of `b=$b` was causing syntax errors. I also couldn't see the reason for `\"` in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Your script could be better. Try reading [**Effective AWK Programming**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) and start again from scratch.

The problem is the last script, which you could have found with some better debugging techniques. A syntactically correct version would be:

```
awk '{for (x=1; x<=no_of_rows; x++) {
        array[x]=r*$3 + a*(($4/nu_not)**b)
        print vector[x]
        print "\n"
     }
 }' nu_not="$nu_not" r="$r" a="$a" b="$b" no_of_rows="$no_of_rows" input
```

The whole script should be written as single `awk` script. Also, `print` **is not** a function in `awk` it's a statement.

Comment: +1 for the nomination. Do I get anything for slogging my way through it to address most of his problems? I probably missed some things, though.

Comment: haha you get a +1 but there a certainly a few more issues that neither of us mention but I get the feeling it's would be a wasted effort here.